# How can I force Déjà-Dup to backup only changed and new files?

Tags: backup, deja-dup

Every day Déjà Dup backups it needs a long time because of my Pictures-folder. Is there a possibility to force Déjà Dup to backup only new and changed files?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I recall, Déjà-Dup will only do incremental updates. Therefore what you are asking for, is exactly what it does already. I'd guess that syncing and comparing just takes a long time. If you want to restore a file via Déjà-Dup from UbuntuOne for example, it will take ages.

Comment: So it does incremental updates? Back In Time was much faster, but may be it depends on encryption. I backup locally. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: @Jakob The encryption is unlikely the cause of any slowness, it's a very small difference. Try switching to weekly backups, so you don't have to wait every day. The occasional full backups will still be slower, but the more common syncs (of just the new or changed content) should only take a few minutes.